# How can I tell what error grub has when I can't read what it's saying?

Tags: grub2

Grub won't allow me to get into any systems on my HP dv7 (it runs 12.10).

As the screen is broken, I can't read what the error is. Nothing works, not even the recovery mode. It gives me some error about "cannot find" (I think) and Press any (I guess key?)

When a press a key I'm dropped back to the menu. At the moment I'm trying all the recovery options I know. However, it would be great if someone could tell me how to know what error grub is facing from a live cd or something (maybe a log file or something could help)?

**NB:**
I can view the filesystem from a liveCD, and I did check the filesystem - it was clean.

Comment: Possible the the error is: `cannot find device for /` or `cannot find a grub drive for /dev/{device}`

Comment: Ever heard of boot-repair? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using boot-repair to fix the problem from a live usb. It turns out that the grub install had been corrupted during an upgrade and needed to be reinstalled cleanly.